# Does windows autorename folder after allocating it as system documents folder

Tags: windows-10, nas, documents

We've placed a NAS as fileserver and moved data there. Now for 4 users, we've mapped a letter to the data share. That data share has 4 subfolders, 1 for every user. We than changed the location of the "documents" to their personal folder on that data share.

After 1 week though, we've seen 2 of the 4 subfolders being renamed to "documents" and changed icon (icon may have been there before). Location path still points to correct location, but it's confusing which folder is which (each folder had the name of the employee in it).

When we check on the NAS, it still has the original folder names, fe "my documents John".

3 of 4 computers run on windows 10, 1 still on windows 7. The renaming happened for 2 users on windows 10.

- Does windows 10 rename the folder automatically?
- Why didn't that happen straight away (took over a week)?
- Why is there an inconsistancy between name in explorer on computer and in file explorer on NAS?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't actually rename them. But it's sure gonna look like it did. The time delay actually is a bit odd. I can only presume it's the consequence of the fact that you've linked semi-critical folders to a remote file system (this is generally not advised btw). I say semi-critical because Windows will have itself a little freak out if it can't find those folders one day. Been there, done that. A better option would have been to mount the folders on the NAS as sub-folders in each user's my-docs folder.

In truth, though, the folders aren't renamed. They just look like it. If you right-click the folders on the NAS and look at the path shown in the properties it should show you what the real folder name is.